# Stuck on weird crash when calling GetFieldID for recovering member id of custom java class in jni

Tags: java, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface

Here is a custom java class:

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.Rect;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static class FaceShape {
        public PointF [] faceProfile;
        public PointF [] leftEyebrow;
        public PointF [] rightEyebrow;
        public PointF [] leftEye;
        public PointF [] rightEye;
        public PointF [] nose;
        public PointF [] mouth;
        public PointF [] pupil;

        float confidence;
    }

    public static class TrackedFace {
        public FaceShape faceShape;
        public Rect faceRect;

        public int frameId;
    }
...
}
```

Now I want to recover field ids for all members of `TrackedFace` in native code:

```cpp
jclass clsTrackedFace = env->FindClass("com/example/myapplication/MainActivity$TrackedFace");
jfieldID faceShapeId = env->GetFieldID(clsTrackedFace, "faceShape", "Lcom/example/myapplication/MainActivity/FaceShape;");
jfieldID faceRectId = env->GetFieldID(clsTrackedFace, "faceRect", "Landroid/graphics/Rect;");
```

logcat of android studio displays following errors when running the program on devices:

```
11-05 21:47:13.232 18792-18792/com.example.myapplication E/art: JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetFieldID called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchFieldError' thrown in unknown throw location
11-05 21:47:13.232 18792-18792/com.example.myapplication E/art:     in call to GetFieldID
11-05 21:47:13.232 18792-18792/com.example.myapplication E/art:     from java.lang.String com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.stringFromJNI()
11-05 21:47:13.232 18792-18792/com.example.myapplication E/art: "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
11-05 21:47:13.232 18792-18792/com.example.myapplication E/art:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x7515afa8 self=0x7f8309a000
11-05 21:47:13.232 18792-18792/com.example.myapplication E/art:   | sysTid=18792 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f8711de30
11-05 21:47:13.232 18792-18792/com.example.myapplication E/art:   | state=R schedstat=( 364733924 74412465 219 ) utm=31 stm=5 core=1 HZ=100
11-05 21:47:13.232 18792-18792/com.example.myapplication E/art:   | stack=0x7ffda7a000-0x7ffda7c000 stackSize=8MB
11-05 21:47:13.232 18792-18792/com.example.myapplication E/art:   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
11-05 21:47:13.232 18792-18792/com.example.myapplication E/art:     at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.stringFromJNI(Native method)
11-05 21:47:13.232 18792-18792/com.example.myapplication E/art:     at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:58)
```

debugger helps me confirm that the exception is raised from the line:

```cpp
jfieldID faceRectId = env->GetFieldID(clsTrackedFace, "faceRect", "Landroid/graphics/Rect;");
```

and I notice **faceShapeId is NULL**, So I basically can assure there are some errors for recovering field id of `faceShape` field, who can help me out?

Comment: It should probably be `"Lcom/example/myapplication/MainActivity$FaceShape;"` or something like that. Use `javah` or some other tool to confirm the correct signature.

Comment: @Michael It worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Lesson learned here:  **ALWAYS** check **ALL** return values for success in JNI code.  You would have caught your problem immediately and not had to deal with a "weird crash" in later code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I got it, thanks :)

Comment: Actually, the signature `"Lcom/example/myapplication/MainActivity/FaceShape;"` comes with autocomplete of Android Studio.

Comment: I diagnosed this as a bug in android studio in another question. Use the signature javah provides, always.